# reverse routing - play 2.2.x application with multiple route files

Tags: scala, playframework

My main routing file in my app is getting a little out of controller so I tried splitting it up among multiple routing files

routes

```
GET           /                      controllers.Application.index
->            /                      someresource.Routes
```

someresource.routes

```
GET           /                      controllers.SomeResource.get()
```

Routing for someresource seems to work fine. However I can't seem to do reverse routing:

example:

```
routes.SomeResource.get().url()
```

Is there a way to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've only gotten this to work by splitting off an entire "subdirectory" of the application. Basically, you have to give your secondary routes a root path other than `/`. Any controllers referenced by the secondary route file also need to be in some sub package of `controllers.`

Here's an example. Note that your `SomeResource` controller is now under `controllers.somepackage` and all routes defined in `someresource.routes` will be prefixed by `/somepath`.

**conf/routes**

```
->   /somepath   someresource.Routes
```

**conf/someresource.routes**

```
GET  /    controllers.somepackage.SomeResource.get()
```

**Reverse-routing in view**

```
@somepackage.routes.SomeResource.get
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't pass an ID value to `get()` since your route definition doesn't allow for it.

Also, reverse routes are compiled into the `controllers` package, so it would be `controllers.ReverseSomeResource.get().url`

You'll find the compiled code in `target/scala_$VERSION/classes_managed` followed by the package naming conventions (`controllers` in this case). And you can use `javap` on the compiled class to inspect its methods.